# GitHub Pages redirects to a different site

Tags: flutter, github, github-pages, flutter-web

So I'm trying to deploy my flutter web app using GitHub pages, but I'm facing a weird issue. So I have my portfolio on [imgkl.github.io](https://imgkl.github.io) and I'm trying to deploy another app called fl_catalogue which has the URL, [imgkl.github.io/fl_catalogue/](https://imgkl.github.io/fl_catalogue/). But when I try to go to the fl_catalogue app, it takes me to my portfolio.

[image: my portfolio]

[image: fl_catalogue]

I'm deploying the site, using this workflow.

```
name: Flutter Web
on:
push:
branches:
  - master
jobs:
 build:
   name: Build Web
   env:
     my_secret: ${{secrets.commit_secret}}
   runs-on: ubuntu-latest
   steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
           channel: 'beta'
      - run: flutter config --enable-web
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter build web --release
      - run: |
          cd build/web
          git init
          git config --global user.email my_email
          git config --global user.name Imgkl
          git status
          git remote add origin https://${{secrets.commit_secret}}@github.com/Imgkl/fl_catalogue.git
          git checkout -b gh-pages
          git add --all
          git commit -m "update"
          git push origin gh-pages -f
```

Comment: so how are you trying to do the deployment? what is your source code/config like?

Comment: @eis I've updated my question, with the workflow that I've used to deploy both of my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did not change the base path in `web/index.html`

```
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">
```